# PyInstaller: .exe runs, throws an exception trying to dynamically load a module

Tags: python-3.x, executable

I've written a Python program using phonenumbers. On my Windows system with Python 3.6.4 installed, it works as intended, but I'd like to redistribute it as a standalone Windows executable, so I've run PyInstaller on it to get a Windows executable.

However, I'm hitting two barriers: first, I'm a rank beginner with Python, and the details of the Python environment are still a slog for me.

Second, the .EXE program throws an exception trying to dynamically load a module (country data to parse a number, FWIW), and I haven't managed to figure out how to incorporate dynamically loaded modules into a standalone executable. (The failure was in a "try" clause, so it took me a while to locate it.) My own system has all the memory I'd need to pre-load all the needed dynamically loaded modules up front, so I'd prefer to do things that way.

Solutions, suggestions, hints, thoughts? A fully-worked example somewhere?  Perhaps I'm failing to understand an answer already in the forum, but that would be because I'm a beginner, so I'd appreciate some clarity.

## ____

Thanks for your notes.  To answer @adnan-y and @apogalacticon: I've made a simple test case. Here are the program source, output from running the script, the pyinstaller run on the program (with no prior build directories or files), its warning file, the result of running the executable, and the location of the file that the Python script correctly loads and correctly uses on the sample input.

#### The source program Parse-failure.py

```
import phonenumbers
Number = "+17034820623"
print("The unprocessed number is <%s>" % (Number))
Parsed_Number = phonenumbers.parse(Number)
print("The parsed number is <%s>" % (Parsed_Number))
```

#### Output from running Parse-failure.py

```
$ Parse-failure.py
The unprocessed number is <+17034820623>
The parsed number is <Country Code: 1 National Number: 7034820623>
```

#### Pyinstaller run

```
$ PyInstaller --onefile Parse-failure.py
94 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4.dev0
94 INFO: Python: 3.6.4
94 INFO: Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
95 INFO: wrote N:\PPR\Parse-failure.spec
96 INFO: UPX is not available.
97 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['f:\\Dems\\PhoneCheck', 'f:\\Dems\\PhoneCheck']
98 INFO: checking Analysis
98 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
98 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
99 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
101 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5155 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
5157 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by d:\python36\python.exe
6356 INFO: Caching module hooks...
6363 INFO: Analyzing N:\PPR\Parse-failure.py
6738 INFO: Loading module hooks...
6739 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
6843 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
6845 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
7238 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
7238 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
7247 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
7372 INFO: Looking for eggs
7372 INFO: Using Python library d:\python36\python36.dll
7372 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
7375 INFO: Warnings written to N:\PPR\build\Parse-failure\warnParse-failure.txt
7461 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to N:\PPR\build\Parse-failure\xref-Parse-failure.html
7471 INFO: checking PYZ
7471 INFO: Building PYZ because out00-PYZ.toc is non existent
7471 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) N:\PPR\build\Parse-failure\out00-PYZ.pyz
8292 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) N:\PPR\build\Parse-failure\out00-PYZ.pyz completed successfully.
8302 INFO: checking PKG
8302 INFO: Building PKG because out00-PKG.toc is non existent
8302 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
10218 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg completed successfully.
10222 INFO: Bootloader d:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
10222 INFO: checking EXE
10222 INFO: Building EXE because out00-EXE.toc is non existent
10222 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
10222 INFO: Appending archive to EXE N:\PPR\dist\Parse-failure.exe
10228 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc completed successfully.
```

#### Warnings file build\PCS\warnParse-failure.txt

```
missing module named resource - imported by posix, n:\PPR\Parse-failure.py
missing module named posix - imported by os, n:\PPR\Parse-failure.py
missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess, n:\PPR\Parse-failure.py
missing module named org - imported by pickle, n:\PPR\Parse-failure.py
missing module named readline - imported by cmd, code, pdb, n:\PPR\Parse-failure.py
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib, importlib.abc, n:\PPR\Parse-failure.py
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap, importlib, importlib.abc, n:\PPR\Parse-failure.py
missing module named _winreg - imported by platform, n:\PPR\Parse-failure.py
missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request
missing module named java - imported by platform, n:\PPR\Parse-failure.py
missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform, n:\PPR\Parse-failure.py, xml.sax._exceptions
missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform, n:\PPR\Parse-failure.py
missing module named termios - imported by tty, n:\PPR\Parse-failure.py, getpass
missing module named grp - imported by shutil, tarfile, n:\PPR\Parse-failure.py
missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath, shutil, tarfile, http.server, webbrowser, n:\PPR\Parse-failure.py, netrc, getpass
missing module named _dummy_threading - imported by dummy_threading, n:\PPR\Parse-failure.py
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by copy, n:\PPR\Parse-failure.py, xml.sax
```

#### Run the executable

```
$ dist\Parse-failure.exe
[1364] Failed to execute script Parse-failure
The unprocessed number is <+17034820623>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Parse-failure.py", line 7, in <module>
    Parsed_Number = phonenumbers.parse(Number)
  File "site-packages\phonenumbers\phonenumberutil.py", line 2835, in parse
  File "site-packages\phonenumbers\phonemetadata.py", line 294, in metadata_for_region_or_calling_code
  File "site-packages\phonenumbers\phonemetadata.py", line 267, in metadata_for_region
  File "site-packages\phonenumbers\data\__init__.py", line 23, in _load_region
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'phonenumbers.data.region_US'
```

#### The location of ...region_US

```
D:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\phonenumbers\data\region_US.py
```

Comment: Add the full error to the question.

Comment: Does PyInstaller successfully build the application? If so, run the executable from the command prompt and add the output to your question as an edit.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Comment: Not resolved. I haven't checked lately whether the latest release of Pyinstaller solves the problem -- a matter of access to a suitably configured Windows system.